# In Android, how to check the contents of an EditTextPreference in my PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences

I have a PreferenceActivity in my Android application to allow the user to configure various parameters.  A few of them are numbers that are entered in EditTextPreferences.  I realize I could use ListPreferences instead, to force the input to be numeric, but the range of allowable values is too large to make that convenient.

Hence, I would like to add code to verify the various entries in an effort to user-proof as best as possible.  I have very similar code elsewhere in the app that checks the contents of some EditText's in a Tab Activity using setOnFocusChangeListener attached to the EditTexts:

```
dataField.setOnFocusChangeListener (new DataFieldFocusChangeListener());
```

This works like a charm.

Unfortunately, it does not appear that the focus change listener for the EditText inside the EditTextPreference inside my PreferenceActivity is ever called.  Can anyone suggest a listener appropriate to this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following listener:-

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // Perform validation here

    }

});
```